# How can i use both onclick() function and POST method with form together? (php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

i am new to php and really need some help. To make some practice i decided to work on a project that has similar points with Twitter .My problem is when i click the submit button, button value didnt change. But if i put my code out of the form then it worked. I need also POST to control if its value follow or followed. If its followed then my code will register id to my database. If it turns follow then will delete the id from db.(I didnt write this part yet and sorry, my code is little bit sketchy). Is there a way to solve my problem? Thank you for your help already.

```
<div id="bilgi">
    <h3>
        <?php
        $name=$row["name"];
        echo $name;
        ?>
    </h3>

    <h5>Hey there! you can follow me if you want to see my tweets.</h5>

    <?php
    if ( $_POST['butt']=="Followed") {
        $sqlr = "INSERT INTO follow(member_email,person_email) VALUES ('$email','$term')";
        $rqu = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlr);
        }    
    ?>

    <div id="bbbb">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input onclick="follow(this)"  type="submit" value="Follow" name="butt" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function follow(element) 
    { 
        if ( element.value === "Follow" )
            element.value = "Followed";
        else
            element.value = "Follow";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: shift the function-binding to form's `onsubmit`. Not 100% sure though..

Comment: and have a look at [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)!

Comment: You should do it using ajax something like `if($rqu){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to separate the function that interacts with the database from the page with the button and then access it using ajax. Ajax uses javascript to send a request to another script, for example, your "save contact to database" script, so that you don't leave the page, that way you can click the button again, to toggle following/not following.

jQuery makes ajax really easy, expecially if you're binding events to objects. You should check it out. [jQuery and AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)